# How to call function of main code in an Imported module?

Tags: python, function, class, import, module

Can an imported module make the Main module call a function?
I created a [sequence diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7bRp.png) and I have a barebones code example of what I mean:

main:

```
import test2

def function():
    do sth
```

test2:

```
import tkinter as tk

window  = tk.Tk()
test = tk.Button(master = window, text = "hdsd", command = # call function of main program)
test.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to design your imported code so that you are only importing objects (functions, classes, constants) and not running code. Then, once you have functions or classes, you can pass other functions or objects to them.

For example, consider this **main.py**:

```
import test2
def function():
    do sth
test2.create_gui(function)
```

**test2.py** might then look like this:

```
def create_gui(func):
    window  = tk.Tk()
    test = tk.Button(master = window, text = "hdsd", command = func)
    test.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    window.mainloop()
```

Arguably, a better solution is to use classes, both for the code in **main.py** and in **test2.py**. By adding all of the functions into a class, you can pass one instance and your GUI will have access to all of the functions.

**main.py**

```
from test2 import GUI
class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.gui = GUI(self)

    def function(self):
        do sth

    def another_function(self):
        do sth

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
    main.gui.start()
```

**test2.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, main):
        super().__init__()
        test1 = tk.Button(self, text="hdsd", command=main.function)
        test2 = tk.Button(self, text="sdhd", command=main.another_function)

        test1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        test2.grid(row=0, column=1)

    def start(self):
        self.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I've struggled to do this all day.
However I left out the self in '''super().__init__()''' because it caused a '''TypeError: create() argument 1 must be str or None, not GUI'''
I hope this causes no problems further down the line

Comment: @Dashy: sorry about that. I updated the answer to fix that problem.